# I have to iterate inside an array and display elements with a setTimeout by modifying the src of an image

Tags: jquery, arrays, image, for-loop, settimeout

What I have to do is: iterate inside a nested array, which I access correctly, and I have to do it in time. Every "x" seconds I have to modify the "src" and the "rel" of an existing image (applying a fade in and out), I tried to iterate with a for loop as in the example but all I always get is only the last of the options, which is the last of the array elements

```
arr = [abc.png, def.png, ghi.png];
for(let i=0; i<3; i++) {    
  val = arr[i]
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#example").html("<img src="+val+ "rel=" +val+ "style='width:100%'>");
  }, 1000) }
```

Comment: Maybe you should re-render in each loop?

Comment: I've already tried to return the jquery element inside the setTimeout and it doesn't work anyway, if that's what you mean

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is after 1000sec when the code inside the timer runs the loop already triggered the timer again.
Also you will always have only the last item set at the end of the loop.
Reason is you change the same static element.

If I understand this correct you want to change the image every x seconds

Perhaps something like this can help

So we use a timer to determine when we change the image (every 1sec)
and we **Self-Invoking** function to repeat the process

JavaScript:

```
let imagesArray = [
    "https://i.picsum.photos/id/1010/200/200.jpg?hmac=030jCT8DyI2wW-CYue7-l9xlHBAGpacaSJ6tYnnka3I", 
    "https://i.picsum.photos/id/373/200/200.jpg?hmac=WAwyn7yIFXuyUxxF4b3ijw7qJfIP7oBXicnozVoLj_o", 
    "https://i.picsum.photos/id/70/200/200.jpg?hmac=hRU7tEHltyLUTf0bCrAWFXlPRXOBTsvCcvL-dIUG2CE"];
let imageIndex = 0;
function setImageFunction(){
    //Get the image from the list of images
    let imageUrl = imagesArray[imageIndex];
    //If we have reached the end set imageCount back to 0
    if(imageIndex == imagesArray.length){
        imageIndex = 0;
    }else
    {
         //otherwise go to next index
        imageIndex++;
    }
    //set the image here
     document.getElementById("example").src = imageUrl;
 
    //Call the iteself to continue the process
    setTimeout(setImageFunction, 1000);
}
setImageFunction();
```

HTML

```
<img id="example" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x360/fff/aaa" >
```

And here is the fiddler
https://jsfiddle.net/604rvzpg/

Comment: function setImageFunction() {
        for(let i=0; i<3; i++) {
            let val = imagesArray[i]
            $("#example").html('<img src=./'+val+ ' rel="'+val+'" style="width:100%">').fadeIn("slow").fadeOut("slow")

            setTimeout(setImageFunction,2000)

        }

Comment: this code gaves me an infinite loop and gave me only the last item still... don't know why..

Comment: But with that you are still doing the same thing :(

As stated in the answer above your problem is the code you are writing.
you are calling a timer in a for loop.
That means it will call the timer for every loop as fast as it compiles. In this case faster than the timer actually executes.

You need to perhaps rethink the solution. For example the one i mentioned above.

Can you state the result or behavior you are looking for?

Comment: Oh.. you are right, sorry and thanks!